# Сортировка многомерного массива по значению

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет. Листая `foreach (products as product)` имею на странице много товаров примерно такого содержания:

```
 [2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 295
        [viewed] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [chat_id] => 74
                        [message_id] => 162
                        [status] => 0
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [chat_id] => 74
                        [message_id] => 163
                        [status] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
```

В SQL сделать сортировку возможности нет.

Как можно сделать сортировку, чтоб товары где есть `[status] => 0` были вначале списка?

Другими словами если в чате есть хоть одно непрочитанное сообщение поднять его вверх списка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
usort($products, function($a) {
  foreach ($a["viewed"] as $viewed)
    if (!$viewed["status"]) return 0;
  return 1;
});
```

Описание, как и просили:

`usort($products, function($a, $b) { ... });` позволяет отсортировать массив, используя пользовательскую функцию, в которую передаются первые два индекса этого массива (`$a` и `$b`), второй из которых в данном случае не требуется. По возвращаемым значениям пользовательской функции определяется порядок, в котором будет выводиться элемент `$a`.

Comment: где используется $b?

Comment: @ultimatum, да в принципе она в данном случае и не нужна, я так думаю. немного поправил.

Comment: порядок вывода не поменялся, ошибок нет. выполняю ДО foreach (products as product)

Comment: @ultimatum, я правильно понял? если хотя бы в одном элементе массива views статус равен нулю, то поместить продукт в начало списка?

Comment: да. все верно.(другими словами если в чате есть хоть одно непрочитанное сообщение поднять его вверх списка)

Comment: @ultimatum, пардон. запостил и не проверил :)

Comment: @ultimatum, смысл в том, что при сортировке проверяется `$product["viewed"]` на наличие вложенного массива со значением `"status" => 0`. если значение найдено, возвращается 0, иначе 1. По этим цифрам, в конце концов и производится сортировка. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Work! Коротко и функционально. Спасибо большое!

Comment: если не будет сложно, добавьте пож в ответ описание функционала

Comment: спасибо за описание

Answer (score 2):

```
//Сортируем сообщения внутри "viewed"
foreach($products as &$product){
    usort($product['viewed'], function($a,$b){
        if($a["status"] < $b['status']) return 1;
        if($a["message_id"]==$b["message_id"])return 0; //Если они не могут быть равными, то можно удалить эту строку
        return $a["message_id"]<$b["message_id"];
    });
}

//Сортируем $products по статусам вложенных сообщений. Внутри viewed мы уже отсортировали
usort($products, function($a,$b){return $a["viewed"][0]<$b["viewed"][0];})
```

Comment: не совсем, меняет сортировку, не все NEW вверху. Оставлю принятый ответ, т.к. он короче и корректно отрабатывает. Сенкс.

Answer (score -1):

Костыльный вариант, мб ктото придумает умнее, но все же:

```
$status_array = array(//Массив, в который мы будем записывать товары
    0 => array(),
    1 => array()
)
foreach($products as $product){
    $zero_status = false;//Если мы так и не найдем НОВЫЕ записи(статус==0)
    foreach($product[viewed] as $prod_detail){
        $status = $prod_detail[status]; //получаем статус текущего товара(?)
        if($status == 0){    
            $status_array[0][] = $product; //записываем его в соответствующий массив
            $zero_status = true;
            break;//Искомое условие мы нашли, выходим
        }
    }
    if(!zero_status){
        $status_array[1][] = $product; 
    }
}
$status_array = array_merge($status_array[0],$status_array[1]);
//получаем общий массив, где сначала идут записи со status = 0
```

Comment: внутри одного товара их может быть дюжина и больше

Comment: @ultimatum Исправил ответ

Comment: в нашем деле есть прогресс, 
сортировка работает! но не корректно, выводит только те продукты где есть NEW. А как же остальные ?)

Comment: @ultimatum, да, и правда, я совсем забыл. Ответ исправлен, теперь должны добавляться все записи.

Comment: не совсем делает кучу дублей + тянет 1 товар из [0]

Comment: @ultimatum whoops, промахнулся foreach'ем, fix'd